# How get direct download link for a video from YouTube in java?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-dl

I have tried the codes libraries and APIs and most of them did not work or are very old. I need a way to get a direct download link for a video from YouTube in java (android studio) and it is a permanent method and not a temporary method.  Thanks

Comment: write the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I build my own library to extract Youtube Stream Link [kotlin-youtubeExtractor](https://github.com/maxrave-dev/kotlin-youtubeExtractor).

You need to use Kotlin Coroutines with my library:

```
scope.launch {
            val ytFiles = YTExtractor(context).getYtFile(videoId)
            var streamUrl = ytFiles[251].url
        }
```

More information in [kotlin-youtubeExtractor](https://github.com/maxrave-dev/kotlin-youtubeExtractor)